# How to remove first_link & last_link from pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to remove or disable the first and last buttons from pagination.
I don't want to appear on the page or insert its code.

I did the following

```
$config['first_link'] = "";
$config['last_link'] = "";
```

but still appear on the page.

[image]

**How to resolve this problem ?**

Comment: Did you try: ''If you do not want this link rendered, you can set its value to FALSE.''? (from documentation)

Comment: Did you initialize your `$config` with `$this->pagination->initialize($config);` ?

Comment: system/libraries/pagination.php var $first_link=''; var $next_link= ''; make it blank and then try

Answer (score 8):

Try This ...

set a `first link` and `last link` false

```
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
```